# Validating the presence of a dynamically created object with a particular value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models `Company` and `Person`.  They are related such that `Company has_many :people`.  You can add any number of people to `Company` through the use of cocoon.  A person has several fields, one of which is a boolean `:boss`.

I would like to design create a validation to make sure that when a Company saves, it looks to make sure that at least one of its people is a boss (`boss: :true`).

Now I can check to make sure that a company has people with

```
validates_presence_of :people
```

But I'm after something like

```
validates_presence_of people.where(boss: true)
```

Is there a quick, clean way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let create custom method for validation

```
validate :at_least_one_person_is_boss

def at_least_one_person_is_boss
  if self.people.where(boss: true).count == 0
    errors.add(:people, "at least one person is boss")
  end
end
```